# Private Variables in Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We use aura:attribute to share values between controllers and helpers, but this exposes the variable to parents components, because a parent component can set the value.
How can I declare something like a private variable?
Do you have any idea?

An example MyComponent

```
<aura:attribute name="myVar" type="Object"/>
```

My controllers use myVar

```
action1 : function (cmp ) {
  cmp.set("v.myVar, 'some value');

action2 : function (cmp) {
  cmp.get('myVar');
```

But other components can set my attribute in this way. I don't want this.  Example

```
<c:MyComponent myVar='I don't want set myVar here' />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your MyComponent definition, specify access="private" for your attribute.

`<aura:attribute name="myVar" type="Object" access="private"/>`

Docs: [Attribute Access Control](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/access_attr.htm)